# Any sites/books/tricks to practice recursion and OO design?

Tags: java, recursion, oop

I just wanted to know if there are any sites which have problems for practicing recursion and OO design(given a few entities designing the class/interface structure)?

I understand the solutions to problems needing recursion without any difficulties but I can't seem to apply recursion to a new problem.Are there any tricks to apply recursion? I apologize if this question is very dumb!

Comment: To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Comment: GNU means "GNU Not Unix"  In Java most problems are best solved using loops, so don't be surprised if you can't find a good example. In most functional/logic programing languages recursion is more often a natural choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to look at something like [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) or [USACO](http://ace.delos.com/usacogate). They provide many problems ranging from simple to hard and many of them can be solved using recursive techniques. As you proceed you will have a chance to see how others may have solved the problems that you attempt. This way you not only learn recursion but many other problem solving techniques.

Comment: Also,are there any sites where I can practice Object Oriented design related problems?

Comment: OOD is a little harder to find such a site since its not so much programming as it is design. Apart from using a good book such as Head First OOD I'm not sure what to recommend. It will have to come from attempting various projects.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, implement a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) and its operations

Answer (score 1):

try http://programmingpraxis.com

It has got questions/sample examples on recursion

example:write a recursive program that prints numbers from 1 to 10,fibonnaic series

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, recursion is used most on more mathematical algorithm design, but in higher level programming (and OOP is usually higher level), the use of recursion doesn't always add much. Also, recursive procedures are usually not easily adapted, so if one of the requirements changes, it might cause you to rewrite the whole procedure, whereas in more linear programming you could easier get something in or leave it out - they intermediate steps don't depend on each other as much.

Also, in (some?) object oriented languages, for every level of recursion a new instance of an object is created and this causes overhead.

It's a nice technique to know, but depending on the sort of prolems, you might not encounter real life use of it much in OO problems. Apart from a file/directory script I've basically rewrote most of my cool recursive solutions to boring linear ones for performance or maintainability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What problems are you running into?  I would suggest given one of the new problems you have another chance.  If you can't get it to work post a simple example of what you have and what you are trying to do and someone might be able to see what part is tripping you up.

Comment: I was trying to generate unique 7 digit numbers on a telephone pad simulating the movements of chess pieces.In first place,how do I make an efficient object oriented design to represent all the objects? After that, I had no clue of simulating the movements of the chess pieces.There are so many possibilities!

Comment: Maybe try a simpler example first.